# Is it possible to connect 2 or 3 SSAS Cubes to Power bi and create views?

Tags: powerbi, ssas

We have three multidimensional cubes.
Is it possible to connect to the same powerbi dashboard? and create different views on the same dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can pin visuals from multiple reports to a dashboard and each report can be built from a different cube, so I'd think the answer is yes. However, you can't connect to multiple cubes in the same report and separate reports are not going interact at all (e.g. no cross-filtering or shared slicers).